# Index only some fields in ElasticSearch from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch 0.90.2 and elasticsearch-river-mongodb 1.7.0 to retrieve data from mongodb's oplog. In the collection I'm trying to index I have thousands of structured records, let's just named them 'field1', 'field2', 'field3'...'field10'

Is there a way to index only 'field1' and 'field2' ?
Does it matter if these as strings or date objects ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used river plugins, but one thing that I know is you can control index upon fields through mapping or template.
For each field, you can specify the property "index", in mapping or template, to three different options: analyzed, not_analyzed, no. This is the official documentation.

> Set to **analyzed** for the field to be indexed and searchable after being broken down into token using an analyzer. **not_analyzed** means that its still searchable, but does not go through any analysis process or broken down into tokens. **no** means that it won’t be searchable at all (as an individual field; it may still be included in _all). Setting to **no** disables include_in_all. Defaults to analyzed.

If you want your field still be searchable, go with "not_analyzed", otherwise "no".
The type of fields should not matter.

Here is a mapping example from official website

```
{
    "tweet" : {
        "properties" : {
            "user" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
            "message" : {"type" : "string", "null_value" : "na"},
            "postDate" : {"type" : "date"},
            "priority" : {"type" : "integer"},
            "rank" : {"type" : "float"}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Zhoutuo! Your answer helped. I created the index, then I created the mapping and then I attached the mongodb river on that index.